# Change PageView form SideMenu flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview, side-menu

How can i change  Pageview's pages directly from Sidebar Menu according to each Button.
Below the screenshot of the web application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0msBB.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using PageView you can use this approach;

```
//class variable
final _screens = [
  const Page1(),
  const Page2(),
  const Page3(),
];

_currentIndex = 0;

//your start page
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      _screens[_currentIndex],
      //some code
    ],
  ),
);
```

And you can change _currentIndex my tapping your left side buttons. (with setState() method)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, using this method it will be possible to change the side pages without hidden sidebar menu, i wrapped these widgets in Row Widget.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly

Comment: ur welcome, good codings

Comment: @HenriquesArrone I had never thought about it, that's a nice approach.